# Tailwind CSS: The `focus:border-2` class does not exist, but `focus:rotate-2` does

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, postcss

I am using Tailwind CSS with Vue 3, and it looks like that I cannot change border width of input element on focus. I my index.css I have:

```
form-input {
    @apply block appearance-none mb-1 bg-white w-full border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500 focus:border-2 disabled:bg-gray-200
}
```

And I get the error:
*The `focus:border-2` class does not exist, but `focus:rotate-2` does. If you're sure that `focus:border-2` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.*

Am I doing something wrong?
package.json
"tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",

Comment: Are you able to figure out what was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This answer helped me:

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/1889#discussioncomment-23241

> It's important to understand that @apply will not work for inlining pseudo-class or responsive variants of another utility. Instead, apply the plain version of that utility into the appropriate pseudo-selector or a new media query:

```css
    /* Won't work: */
    .btn {
      @apply block bg-red-500;
      @apply hover:bg-blue-500;
      @apply md:inline-block;
    }

    /* Do this instead: */
    .btn {
      @apply block bg-red-500;
    }
    .btn:hover {
      @apply bg-blue-500;
    }
    @screen md {
      .btn {
        @apply inline-block;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enable the `border` class in `focus` variant in the config :

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    extend: {
      border: ['focus'],
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: The error remains...

Comment: please share your `tailwind.config.js` file

Comment: module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.vue"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ['disabled'],
      border: ['focus']
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to change the width this will work:

```
ring-2
```

You should this if you want to change the color:

```
focus:ring-blue-500
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/ring-width

Comment: I dont want a ring